# Does configuring a web server with SSL break regular HTTP

Tags: apache, web-services, http, ssl, https

I'm in the process of getting a SSL certificate for my website which i'm running of a VPS. My website also serves as a web service for some ios/android applications to fetch data from. I'm just wondering if installing and configuring a SSL Certificate in Apache will force everyone to contact the web server over HTTPS and refuse regular HTTP calls. Hince will my applications break until I've released an update making all server calls to HTTPS?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Apache can handle both http and https at the same time.

Normally you setup your http site under something like httpd.conf which includes a line (might be commented out) something like:
Include extra/httpd-ssl.conf

which tells apache to load additional configuration for the httpd-ssl.conf file located in the 'extra' directory.
if you did a standard install of apache then the httpd-ssl.conf file is already there with a generic template for the HTTPS site, just modify it as necessary and (if needed) uncomment the Include line above in httpd.conf.